# Including the end node in a Linked List

Tags: c++, optimization, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list in C++ and I am trying to decide which is better: including the end node in the class (thus increasing its size) or not including it (thus decreasing its but also increasing the time to add to the end and whatnot).

My thinking is that since a Node object is relatively small compared to the standard 4-8 GB of RAM that is common now-a-days, it is well worth the extra space to save time.

But I am wondering if anyone can tell me if I am wrong or any instances of you deciding with one or the other for whatever reasons.

Comment: No need to yell at you, but this is, unfortunately, off topic: primarily opinion-based: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: "any instances of you deciding with one or the other for whatever reasons" come again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which one is better depends entirely on your use case. There are use cases for not including `end` and only supporting iteration in a single direction (for which we have `std::forward_list`) and there are use cases for taking the extra memory and creating a doubly linked list (for which we have `std::list`).

There is no one true "better" container option. It depends on which operations your program needs to do more of. Each container has its own niche.

Except `std::vector`. It's just awesome.

Comment: That's what I thought everyone would say but I had to ask. Thanks